# Call.onStateChanged method is having problem while call is on hold

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to toast the call status. All things are going well but there is some problem while the outgoing call is on hold. 
My "newState" is not equal to "3" and "6".
App is working fine with all other states.

I also tried to log the values of `newState` but nothing happened.

```
@Override
       public void onStateChanged(Call call, int newState) {
           super.onStateChanged(call, newState);

           Log.i(TAG, "onStateChanged: call : " + call.toString());
           Log.i(TAG, "onStateChanged: " + newState);

           Toast.makeText(context, Constants.asString(newState)+" / ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

           state.onNext(newState);
       }
```

And here is the Constants.java

```
public static String asString(int data) {
        String value;
        switch (data) {
            case 0:
                value = "NEW";
                break;
            case 1:
                value = "DIALING";
                break;
            case 2:
                value = "RINGING";
                break;
            case 3:
                value = "HOLDING";
                break;
            case 4:
                value = "ACTIVE";
                break;
            case 6:
                value = "REJECTED";
                break;
            case 7:
                value = "DISCONNECTED";
                break;
            case 8:
                value = "SELECT_PHONE_ACCOUNT";
                break;
            case 9:
                value = "CONNECTING";
                break;
            case 10:
                value = "DISCONNECTING";
                break;
            default:
                Timber.w("Unknown state " + data);
                value = "UNKNOWN";
                break;
        }
```